# Unable to find tbl child nodes in MS Word doc using xpath or $node->children()

Tags: php, xml, xpath, ms-word

I have a project where I am attempting to take a docx file then unzip it, then run through the document.xml file using xpath in order find all table elements. then within each table element run through and identify specific tables using the tblCaption (Table Caption obviously) attribute and then run through the table and find table cells. Then I will change background color of cells by changing the w:fill value using a string replace. We're doing it like this because we want to manually enter tables into Word and then change the table without having to dynamically generate tables using a library like PHPDocx or otherwise. I have so far used SimpleXML with xpath to find all tables in the doc, loop through them and test for the existence and value of the tblCaption node. If there is a match I will then assign bg color to each cell using the cell text to id the cell node. I can find all the tables using xpath. I have attempted to find child nodes of each table using both $tblNode->children() and $xpath:

```
    $xml =    simplexml_load_file(APPPATH.TEMPLATE_UPLOAD_PATH.'xmltest/word/document.xml');

    $namespaces = $xml->getDocNamespaces(true);
    foreach ($namespaces as $prefix => $ns) {
        $prefix = $prefix  == '' ? 'default' : $prefix;
        $xml->registerXPathNamespace($prefix, $ns);
    }

    $nodes = $xml->xpath("/w:document/w:body//w:tbl");

    foreach($nodes as $node) {
        $children = $node->xpath("/w:tblCaption");
        echo count($children) . '<br />';
        //$children = $node->children();
        //echo count($children) . '<br />';
    }
```

I would eventually like to use:
 $children = $node->xpath("/w:tblCaption[@val='whatever']"); to return a tblCaption node only if it exists and has a specific value.

At the moment there are zero child nodes for each tbl node being returned.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems that I can identify having no previlage to see sample XML is, that your code attempt to get element relative to other element by using absolute XPath expression (one that starts with `/`, which reference root document). You should, at least, add a `.` at the beginning of your XPath or remove the `/` completely. Both will result in an XPath that look for child element of certain name, relative to current `$node` :

```
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    $children = $node->xpath("w:tblCaption");
    echo count($children) . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ditched this all together and I'm using the OpenTBS plugin for changing table appearance in Word. It's much more powerful than trying to mess around with xml elements yourself. I haven't tried the above idea. Buy thanks anway.